# What are all the infamy skills?

Tags: payday-2

There are 14 infamy skills in the infamy tree, but I can only see 5 of them.

[image: ?????????]

What are *all* of the skills and what do they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infamy tree has changed since the question was asked and now contains 25 infamy levels in total.

The original 5 perks are found in the center, and are highlighted in the image below. The circled perks unlock a mask, a pattern and a material in addition to a small EXP boost. The rest of the perks offer a slightly larger EXP boost.

[image: full infamy perk tree]

## In greater detail

### EXP perk

Permanent 10% EXP boost

### Mask perks

*From left to right, top to bottom*

*one of the original 5

#### Heister Sentry

- Heister Sentry mask
- Monster Visor pattern
- Alien Slime material
- 7.5% EXP boost

#### Lurker

- Lurker mask
- Hell's Anchor pattern
- Baby material
- 7.5% EXP boost

#### The Being

- The Being mask
- Steampunk pattern
- Punk material
- 7.5% EXP boost

#### The Assassin Set*

- The Spectre mask
- Ribcage pattern
- Sinister material
- Ghost and Fugitive skill point requirements for each tier are 10% lower (doesn't stack)
- 5% EXP boost

#### Balaclava

- Balaclava mask
- Pain pattern
- Eye material
- 7.5% EXP boost

#### Set of the Corrupted*

- The Plague Doctor mask
- Imperial pattern
- Dark Leather material
- Mastermind and Fugitive skill point requirements for each tier are 10% lower (doesn't stack)
- 5% EXP boost

#### Unlocking the Infamy Tree*

- The Heat mask
- Infamous base drop rate increased
- 5% EXP boost
- Cash cost for skills reduced by 25%

#### The Slaughterhouse Set*

- The Butcher mask
- Bounty Hunter pattern
- Copper material
- Enforcer and Fugitive skill point requirements for each tier are 10% lower (doesn't stack)
- 5% EXP boost

#### Android

- Android mask
- Digital pattern
- Haze material
- 7.5% EXP boost

#### Set of the Ingenious*

- The Specialist mask
- Guardian pattern
- Electric material
- Technician and Fugitive skill point requirements for each tier are 10% lower (doesn't stack)
- 5% EXP boost

#### Kamul

- Kamul mask
- Evil Eye pattern
- Plastic Hood material
- 7.5% EXP boost

#### Demonshank

- Demonshank mask
- Ex Machinima pattern
- Arizona material
- 7.5% EXP boost

#### Venger

- Venger mask
- Spook pattern
- Hades material
- 7.5% EXP boost

Answer (score 3):

At this current time, the other infamy skills have not yet been released. They cannot be unlocked, and no official information about them has been released.

From the [official update information](http://www.overkillsoftware.com/infamy/):

> At the launch of infamy, only the unlock point and tier one are available. The remaining tiers will be unlocked at a later date. We'll let you know.